# Run script every 1st and 4th time inside a PHP while loop based on MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I have a `while` `loop` fetching data from a `MySQL` table. The number of returned rows is unknown. I want to run parts of code inside the `loop` on every 1st and 4th item, like:

```
while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) {

   //Run on first row always, then repeat on the 4th item and so on.
   echo '<div class="row">';

}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: simple if/else with flag variable which stores loop iteration

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

```
// keep track of the iteration count
$i = 1;

while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) {

    //if it's the first iteration, open the row
    if($i == 1) { echo '<div class="row">'; }

    //...

    // NOTE: count($results) is pseudocode, make sure you provide it somehow
    // if you're on the 4nth or the last iteration 
    if($i % 4 == 0 or $i == count($results))
    {
        // close the row
        echo '</div>';

        // if it's not the last item in the loop, open a new row
        if($i != count($results)) { echo '<div class="row">'; }
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Where does `$results` come from?

Comment: It's pseudocode, as the comment says. I don't know where the results come from or how to count them. I've made it more clear now.